# Error using Google Play Game Service Cordova Plugin on phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, ant, google-play-services, phonegap-build

I am using 
      
in my config.xml to use the plugin.
I get the following errors in the log after building using pgb.How to fix this issue?.Thanks.
-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 11 source files to /project/bin/classes
    [javac] warning: /project/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar(com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: /project/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar(com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] /project/src/com/a42/cordova/plugins/GooglePlayGame.java:46: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class GoogleGameService
    [javac] location: class com.a42.cordova.plugins.GooglePlayGame
    [javac]     private GoogleGameService googleGameService = new GoogleGameService();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /project/src/com/a42/cordova/plugins/GooglePlayGame.java:46: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class GoogleGameService
    [javac] location: class com.a42.cordova.plugins.GooglePlayGame
    [javac]     private GoogleGameService googleGameService = new GoogleGameService();
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] Note: /project/src/org/apache/cordova/media/AudioPlayer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: /project/src/com/lampa/startapp/startApp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 2 errors
    [javac] 2 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Here is my config.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id          = "com.game.widthxht"
versionCode = "10" 
version     = "1.0.0" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>W x Ht</name>
```

```
<description>
  Game
</description>

<author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="kaushik7ronaldo@gmail.com.com">
  Kaushik 
</author>
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.8" />
 <gap:plugin name="com.a42.cordova.googleplaygame" source="plugins.cordova.io" > <param name="APP_ID" value="651010955617" /> </gap:plugin> 
 <gap:plugin name="net.tunts.webintent" version="0.2.1" />
 <gap:plugin name="com.lampa.startapp" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you confirm: 1) Are you building locally on your computer or through the PhoneGap Build service at build.phonegap.com 2) If you are building locally are you using `phonegap build` or `cordova build`? 3) If you are using build.phonegap.com can you show your config.xml entry? Thank you

Comment: I am using phonegap build.I will edit the question with my config.xml for you to refer. @dawson-loudon

Comment: Ok, the issue you are having is this: Build.phonegap.com only allows the use of approved plugins. You can find that list here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins  Any plugins not listed here do not work with building from this service. You will need to use the `cordova CLI` and build locally from your own computer to use the plugins you have selected.

Comment: Yeah.But this plugin from the same source works perfectly fine. http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.lampa.startapp @DawsonLoudon

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, phonegap build allows plugins from plugins.cordova.io

Comment: @kaushikreddy, the error says that the google play services version (51) is newer than the latest supported by the compiler (50), so contact phonegap build team, maybe they can update the compiler (they should)

Comment: I posted the issue..Havent got any replies yet.. @jcesarmobile